# DJANGO ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'

Tags: python, django

Изучаю Django по видеоуроку. Но столкнулся с ошибкой, над которой мучаюсь уже часа 4, непрерывно гугля и правя. Но безрезультатно.

У меня DJango 1.9

В приложении блог в моделях прописано следующее:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

При попытке открыть в Админке Articles выдает ошибку:
OperationalError at /admin/blog/article/
no such column: blog_article.user_id

При попытки миграции базы (migrate) выдает следующий код:

```
WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DIRS.
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, blog, admin, auth, contenttypes
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying blog.0002_article_user...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.5\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/djangoprojects/MyBlog\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 229, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_fields=[field])
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 111, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(field)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 210, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py", line 915, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.target_field.get_db_prep_save(value, connection=connection)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 728, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 968, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 976, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'
```

В видео у него всё работает, но у меня нет. Уже пересмотрел несколько раз всё равно.

Comment: Выложите traceback или сами посмотрите на какую строчку кода указывает traceback. Еще попробуйте создать пустую базу и на ней запустить миграцию. Если все нормально пройдет, то дело в данных и надо создать миграцию данных.

Comment: выложил сверху в основной пост. Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на то, что поле `user` было создано давно, но раньше оно было `CharField` и в нем хранится имя пользователя в виде строки - "admin"

Теперь вы хотите изменить его на `ForeignKey`, но миграция не проходит из-за старого значения в базе.

Можете показать миграцию?

Решением может быть сначала удаление поля `user` и следом создание нового.